# Haxe: Null object pattern for iterables

Tags: object, design-patterns, null, haxe, iterable

I'd like to implement Null Object design pattern for Iterable class. For example if my internal array isn't initialized, wrapper class anyway returns empty Iterator that doesn't break main logic:

```
public function iterator():Iterator<T> {
  // ...of cause it doesn't work, because Iterator is typedef not class
  return mList != null ? mList.iterator() : new Iterator<T>();
}

var mList:Array<T>;
```

Should I instantiate static empty dummy array with desired type of items or something else that implements Iterator interface but contains nothing? Or may be there is more straight solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the check at forehand in the object class itself, by adding some kind of isEmpty function:

```
public function isEmpty():Bool {
  return mList == null || mList.length == 0;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if(!iter.isEmpty()) {
  for(i in iter) {
    trace(i);
  }
}
```

Example: http://try.haxe.org/#8719E

Or

You could use a dummy iterator for this:

```
class NullIterator  {
    public inline function hasNext() return false;
    public inline function next() return null;
    public inline function new() {}
}
```

.. and use it like this

```
public function iterator():Iterator<T> {
  return mList != null ? mList.iterator() : new NullIterator();
}
```

Example: http://try.haxe.org/#B2d7e

If you think the behavior should be changed, then you could raise an issue on Github.
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues